# How to change behaviour of android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android

I am using android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to capture images, however on pressing Ok button the camera activity is closed and I received the result in onActivityResult. Is there a way the image capture activity can be kept running after pressing OK button. 
At the moment I am starting it again through my onActivityResult function, is it possible that I can keep the same image capture activity running after a successful image capture.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent. Instead you will have to control the camera preview in `SurfaceHolder`. Here is one example I have found - [How to Program the Google Android Camera to Take Pictures](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I want to avoid using the camera class and would prefer to use the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. I know from little time I have spent so far on Android that I can define how my acitivity is laucnhed i.e. launchMode = standard, singleTask, singleTop etc. Is there a way I can start the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to launch one instance so android can keep using that rahter than closing and restarting the same activity.

Comment: Do you mean you want the system to persist the state between two calls to ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE? What is your original purpose in keeping this 'clicked image' still shown to the user?